# Iterate through class properties using reflection

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I'm trying to iterate through my class properties using reflection, I've tried using a few threads on here as guidance but the propertyInfo array is always returning nothing.

```
Public Sub GetProperties(ByRef objType As Type)

    Dim propertyInfo() As PropertyInfo = objType.GetProperties((BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))

    For Each propertyItem As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In propertyInfo
        Console.WriteLine(propertyItem.Name & " is of type " & propertyItem.PropertyType.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    Next

End Sub

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Public Class Collection
    Inherits AppBase
    Public Sub New(ByVal newConnectionString As String, ByVal newAppBrand As String, ByVal newRepID As Integer)
    MyBase.New(newConnectionString, newAppBrand, newRepID)
End Sub

Public Class CollectionRecord
    Inherits AppRecord

    Public collectionID As Integer
    Public name As String
    Public sqmBasePrice As Long
    Public summary As String
    Public imageName As String
End Class

Module DownloadData
   Public Function CheckData
      Dim collectionRecord as new CollectionRecord
      GetProperties(collectionRecord)
   End Function
End Module
```

If I replace my custom class with say a string type in the GetProperties paramater I get two returned properties.
Any ideas?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: your `CollectionRecord` class has public `Fields` not `Properties`. Either iterate members or declare them as `Public Property Name As String`

Comment: [Properties vs Fields – Why Does it Matter?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx). []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a type `CollectionRecord` that has five fields, but no properties.

```
Public Class CollectionRecord
    Inherits AppRecord

    Public collectionID As Integer
    Public name As String
    Public sqmBasePrice As Long
    Public summary As String
    Public imageName As String
End Class
```

You then use the reflection APIs to iterate through the *properties* of that type.

The solution here is either:

1. Iterate through the fields of your type instead of the properties
2. Redefine your type to have properties instead of fields [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd293589.aspx)

Both 1 & 2 will work, it just depends on your needs.

Comment: Doh, of course they're fields - a dose of tunnel vision where I'm looking solely at the new code, thanks very much for the prompt reply.  GetFields works perfectly.